# How to get get latest nodejs:14 digest version in Docker file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, hash

Is there any command/way to get latest digest(sha256) for amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14. Currently, we are manually setting digest version sha256. Like, give below.

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14@sha256:621368a9c8cbf474b60ae9092725f6ea7ae4f9b0ac7a9229039e25157bad990b
```

We end up getting vulnerabilities after some time for the Docker image. Please suggest a way/command in Dockerfile to get the latest version or stable version while building a Docker image.

Comment: `FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:latest` for latest version, and `FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14` for latest 14.* version. If you have some older 14.* image cached, it'll be used. You'll have you pull the latest.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me for my dumb question @stefan. Are version 14 and the latest are different?. Can u explain me the difference.

Comment: Latest represents the latest version. If tomorrow they release version 15 or 16, that would be the latest version. Version 14 is just version 14. But even version 14 has patches and updates. If you look at [available tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs/tags) for the image you'll see there are versions like `14.2021.12.21.23`, `14.2021.12.21.16`, `14.2021.12.18.00`, etc. When you specify version 14, you'll get the latest image which version begins with `14.`. In this case it would be `14.2021.12.21.23`.

Answer (score 1):

The list of digests for each tag is available from a V2 registry JSON response  for a specific tag in the `images` array:

```
curl -sfL "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs/tags/14" \
 | jq -r '.images[] | "\(.os) \(.architecture) \(.digest)"'
```

Also from a local image in the `RepoDigests` array

```
docker pull amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14
docker inspect amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14 | \
 jq -r '.[].RepoDigests'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify an exact image hash like that, you'll always get that exact image, never a newer version or build.

It's more common to just specify the image tag

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14
```

If you `docker pull` the base image, it will contact the registry and try to get a newer version.  It won't download versions or layers it already has, so this can be quick if the image hasn't changed upstream (or it can be slow if the base OS has an update and you need to download the whole thing again).

```sh
docker pull amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14
docker build .
```

[`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) and [`docker-compose build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) both have `--pull` options that can do this automatically.  If you're using Compose, for example, you can

```sh
docker-compose pull
docker-compose build --pull
docker-compose up -d
```

to get the newest build of any image mentioned in the `docker-compose.yml` file or in Dockerfile `FROM` lines.